# Passing url to Image tag in asp.net C#

Tags: asp.net

I dont know how to pass value from page.aspx.cs (string url = dr["report_image"].ToString();) to page.aspx ( )

i save image filename (eg:sunset.jpg) to sql database and retrieve it using reader (string url = dr["report_image"].ToString();) and i want to use this url (or filename) to use in the main webpage (aspx). I dont know how to pass this value from "*.aspx.cs" to "*.aspx"

Any help would be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:Image ID="img" Runat="Server" />
```

Аnd in the code:

```
img.ImageUrl = url
```

Comment: thank you bob, as you see i'd be having many problems, hope you'r always there.. thank you

Answer (score -1):

or you can simply generate Image element in aspx.cs side.

the code below

```
 Image img = new Image();
 img.ImageUrl = "your string";
```